# Visual studio search keeps files open

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Whenever I search for certain strings in a project, it opens each file that contains that string and keeps it open as a tab even though I do nothing to the files.  Therefore, when I search for a common string, I end up with tons of open tabs on files I don't care about.  Is there a way to stop that?

Answer (score 0):

Tools/Options/Tabs and Windows.

There's a section called Preview Tab.  I think if you check "Allow new files to be opened in the preview Tab" and "Preview selected files in Find Results" this might get what you're seeking.